# Want to use print option in windows 8.1 app store

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8.1, windows-store

I want to print the document with system.print but its not working in windows store app. Can anyone help me, how can the print will work.

I am using XAML for user interface.

Comment: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/10/25/windows-store-apps-and-xaml-based-printing-rough-notes.aspx

Comment: Nice blog you posted, however can it possible we can print the content without previewing as we want to use for POS where only thermal printer can be used.